# How can I open main page if user is logined and tried open login page?(Spring security)

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-boot

I use spring security in my project and I use custom authonticate. I save user from code.

```
@Override
    public void saveUser(AuthLkUser lkUser) {
        final List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER");
        grantedAuths.add(grantedAuthority);
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(lkUser.getMsisdn(), lkUser.getPricePlan(), grantedAuths);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(result);
    }
```

It work normaly. But after succsessufull login, I can open login page again.
I need disable possibility open login page after succsessufull login. I tried this:

```
.antMatchers("/login", "/default/login").access("hasRole('ANONYMOUS')")
```

But user with "USER" role can open login page too.

I tried

```
@Component
public class MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler {
    @Override
    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {
        // initialization logic after login

        // redirect
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        SavedRequest savedReq = (SavedRequest) session.getAttribute("SAVED_REQUEST");
        if (savedReq == null) {
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath() + "/landing");
        }
        else {
            response.sendRedirect(savedReq.getRedirectUrl());
        }
    }
}
```

and setup to config

```
@Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

.successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
```

But after succsessufull login this method not called.

How can I open main page if user is logined and tried open login page?

and why my `myAuthenticationSuccessHandler` not called?

it is my config

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private MyAuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/", "/index").access("hasRole('USER')")
//                .antMatchers("/login", "/default/login").access("hasRole('ANONYMOUS')")
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                .successHandler(myAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .permitAll();
        http.csrf()
                .disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().permitAll()
                .and();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add a controller in which you need to check for login request whether User is already logged in or not. If not logged in than display login page else redirect to home page. Following is such sample controller:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/login",method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(){

        if(SecurityUtils.isUserLoggedIn())
            return "redirect:/home"; 

        return "login";

    }

}
```

And following is sample SecurityUtils.java class which is utility class having method to check whether user is logged in or not :

```
public class SecurityUtils {

    public static boolean isUserLoggedIn(){
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if(null != authentication){
            return (authentication.isAuthenticated() && !(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken));
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: that's exactly what I did. but I think it is a bad practice